# XCODE: How do I hide the cursor from my searchBar after the user is done searching?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, search, cursor

I have looked tirelessly through SO and haven't found out how to do this.  How do I hide the cursor from my searchBar after the user is done searching?  It just keeps blinking when the user doesn't need it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For normal `UITextField`s, if you set the `tintColor` property to `.clear`, the cursor will hide.
Similarly, for a `UISearchBar`, I would try

```swift
let sb = UISearchBar()
sb.searchTextField.tintColor = .clear
```

OR

```swift
let sb = UISearchBar()
sb.tintColor = .clear
```

Let me know if it works.